# Fórmula SE + PROCV terminando em #VALOR!

Tags: microsoft-excel, fórmula, procv

Galera boa tarde.
A formula abaixo está terminando em erro **#VALOR!**.
A formula está comparando palavras com hífen, não sei se isso influencia em algo.

```
=SE(PROCV(R25;'TABELA1'!A:A;1;0);"ERRO DE WORKFLOW";"")
```

Comment: podes postar um print dos dados ou postares um ficheiro exemplo com a indicação do resultado esperado para que seja mais fácil responder.

Comment: Mas a função PROCV retorna ou o valor procurado ou um erro. O que você considera como verdadeiro ou falso para o critério da função SE?

Comment: Talvez você deva utilizar: É.NÃO.DISP(PROCV(R25;'TABELA1'!A:A;1;0)).

Comment: eu upei o exemplo aqui http://www.filetolink.com/d42e073229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SE(PROCV(R25;'TABELA1'!A:A;1;0);"ERRO DE WORKFLOW";"")`, voce precisa definir qual a condição do `SE`, o que voce deseja que o procv retorne, se ele vai ser igual a algo, ou maior/menor, precisa definir isso e depois voce vai mostrar a condição "Erro Worflow" ou "";

Comment: Favor ler [Como formatar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/75104)

Comment: @danieltakeshi vlw, desculpa a demora, li sobre formatação, estou me atentando nesses itens. obrigado !!